# Permission denied for image dompdf even with chroot set

Tags: php, html, dompdf, permission-denied

I am getting errors when I tried to include image in dompdf. I am using version 1.2.1
I tried with base4 encoded image as well from one of the solutions mentioned in forums, that also not working.

```
<?php

namespace Dompdf;
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

$_dompdf_show_warnings = true;
$_dompdf_warnings = [];

$path="http://localhost/dompdf/assets/images/logo.png";
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$image = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);

$htmldata = '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Results</title>
  <style>
  body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
    .container {
      width: 90%;
      max-width: 600px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
      
      <h1>test pdf</h1>
      <img src="/assets/images/logo.png" alt="image">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer egestas elementum justo, eget maximus odio ultricies eu. Aenean faucibus varius massa, sit amet sagittis neque vulputate luctus.</p>

      <img src="'.$image.'" alt="base64">
  </div>

</body>

</html>';


$options = new Options();
$options->getChroot($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/dompdf/");;
$options->setisRemoteEnabled(true);
$options->setIsHtml5ParserEnabled(true);

$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

$dompdf->loadHtml($htmldata);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("",array("Attachment" => false));
exit(0);

?>
```

Getting these errors, first is when I include the image path and second for base64 encoded one. I tried to enable remote, added chroot path and tried several solutions found on internet. Nothing helped.

> Permission denied on /assets/images/logo.png. The file could not be found under the paths specified by Options::chroot. /assets/images/logo.png

> Unable to create temporary image in /var/folders/bc/tnbzrzvd1k370wftgbm5lnqh0000gn/T data:image/;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA

**EDIT:**
Tried with file_exists() from the same directory and it works.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Comment: what is the result of curl http://localhost/dompdf/assets/images/logo.png ?

Comment: @svgta I tried with file_exists() and it works. Can you give me a sample or how to do to with cURL?

Comment: just type "curl localhost/dompdf/assets/images/logo.png" in command line

Comment: @svgta Shows "The requested URL was not found on this server". In file_exists(), I tried the exact chroot path